# property remove from the list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Remove property from a list

```
        NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
        List<CategorySml> oList = new List<CategorySml>();
        oList = db.Categories.Select(p => new CategorySml { CategoryID = p.CategoryID, CategoryName = p.CategoryName }).ToList();

class CategorySml

{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

My list contain more than 100 rows,Now i want to remove **CategoryID** property from my list **oList** .I know how to remove item from a list bellow syntax can do that,but i don't know how to remove property's of a item

```
oList.RemoveAll(x => x.CategoryID== 1);
```

Help me to remove property from a list.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should accept the answers that are correct

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "remove" the property you will have create new type without this property:

```
oList = db.Categories.Select(p => new YourNewCategorySml { 
  CategoryName = p.CategoryName })
  .ToList();
```

or use the anonymous type:

```
oList = db.Categories.Select(p => new { CategoryName = p.CategoryName })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks ,it's a good technique to avoid unwanted properties.thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about inheritance?

```
class BaseCategory
{
  public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
class CategorySml : BaseCategory

{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
}

NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
        List<BaseCategory> oList = new List<BaseCategory>();
        oList = db.Categories.Select(p => new BaseCategory{ CategoryName = p.CategoryName }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by an anonymous type variable

```
try
            {
               NorthwindDataContext db= new NorthwindDataContext();
               var oList = db.Categories.Select(p => new { Categoryname = p.CategoryName }).ToList();                
               dg.DataSource = oList;



                MessageBox.Show("OK"); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
            }
```